# move an image towards the top in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bd2zrm9/3/embedded/result/) in which I want to move an image (keyboard) towards the top so that it looks exactly similar to below design.

[image]

In my fiddle, the keyboard image is slightly down as depicted in the fiddle. I am wondering how can I push my keyboard image slightly up so that it looks exactly similar to the above design.

The snippets of my HTML code having keyboard image are :

```
    <div class="full-stack-developer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-lg-3 left-side">
                    <a href=""><img src="assets/img/Uploads/keyboard.png" </a></div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 right-side"> <a href="">Full Stack Developer</a>
                    <ul>
                        <a href=''>
                            <li>Qualification</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href=''>
                            <li>Go here</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Just checking if it can be done without using `position: relative and position: absolute` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the margin top -50px to the image.

```
#id_keyboard {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2bd2zrm9/5/embedded/result/

Comment: Can it be done by making some changes in the class ?

Comment: What "some changes in the class" do you mean? Check my link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the image and some css as follows:
set an id

```
 <a href=""><img id = "offset" src="https://s10.postimg.org/wz9hbucvd/keyboard.png" </a>
```

move it up a bit

```
#offset{
  margin-top:-40px
}
```